# Swift uitableview json delete row

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a tableview with JSON data where I can delete mysql data by JSON with Delete button action throw a method. But does not find out a way to delete from cell.

Here is screen shot and code
[image]

```
    //Send user data to server side

    @IBAction func deleteData(sender: AnyObject) {
    let adduser = lblName.text
    let id = store.storeId




    //Send user data to server side

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/crud/delete.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "id=\(id)";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);




    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            do{
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON=json{
                    var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as! String
                    print("result: \(resultValue)")


                    var isUserRegistered:Bool = false;
                    if(resultValue=="Success") {isUserRegistered = true;  }

                    var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String

                    if(!isUserRegistered)
                    {
                        messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String;
                    }


                    //self.store.storeName = self.lblName.text!

                    //store?.sName = txtName.text!

                    self.store.storeName = self.lblName.text!






                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        // Display alert message with confirmation.

                        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {action in
                            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);


                        }

                        myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion:nil);
                    });


                }

            }catch{print(error)}


    }
    task.resume()


}
```

**TableViewController**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var storeList = [Store]()

//var storeList:Store?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


      /*
       if let s = storeList
       {
        txtName.text = s.storeName
       }
     */


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
     //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    self.loadRecords()


}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData() // to reload selected cell
}








override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return storeList.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoreTVC



    let s = storeList[indexPath.row] as Store

    cell.lblName.text = s.storeName
    //cell.lblID.text = s.storeId


    return cell
}

// for swipe delete

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        storeList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}




/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    /*

     if segue.identifier == "details"
     {

     //if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        {
            let s = storeList[indexPath.row] as Store

            let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewDetails

            dvc.store = s
        }

    }
   */

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)
    {
        let s = storeList[indexPath.row] as Store

        let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewDetails

        dvc.store = s
    }


}


func loadRecords()
{
    //The address of the web service
    let urlString = "http://localhost/crud/read_for_table_view.php"

    // 1 - Create the session by getting the configuration and then crrating the session

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

    //2 - Create the URL Object

    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    {
        //3 - Create the request object

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        //4 - execute the request

        let taskData = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            //5 - Do something with the Data back

            if(data != nil)
            {
                //we got some data back

                print("\(data)")
                /*
                var  parseError:NSError?

                let parsedStores = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parseError) as! NSDictionary
                */

                do {
                    if let parsedStores = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        print("Json Data \n \(parsedStores)")

                        if let stores:AnyObject = parsedStores["result"]
                        {
                            self.parseJSON(stores)
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }



            }else
            {
                //we got an error
                print("Error getting stores :\(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })

        taskData.resume()

    }

}

func parseJSON(jsonData:AnyObject)
{
    if let storeData = jsonData as? [[NSObject:AnyObject]]
    {
        var store:Store

        //we loop through all the recors and everytime we create
        // an object of kind store and then add to the store list

        for s in storeData
        {
            store = Store()
            // this part is getting the values

            if let sId:AnyObject = s["id"]
            {
                if let storeID = sId as? String
                {
                    print("Store id = \(storeID)")
                    store.storeId = storeID
                }
            }

            if let sn:AnyObject = s["name"]
            {
                if let storeName = sn as? String
                {
                    store.storeName = storeName

                }
            }


            storeList += [store]
        }


        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock()
            {

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
     }
   }
 }
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: didnt get your point..

Comment: means it deletes data to mysql but delete does not reflect the tableview.

Comment: @ EI Captain v2.0 - Yes agreed. But how ?

Comment: So here I updated with full method.

Comment: Yes. As shown in picture tableview is in one controller. It has details in another controller where it has a button and a method to delete.

Comment: @tanvir you call any service on that table viewcontroller to get data

Comment: Yes web service with json.

Comment: then it should not get that deleted row .... you got an updated data if service is in `viewWillAppear`  ...  print your response and check you get updated data or not

Comment: @EI Captain v2.0 - Did not work either.

Comment: @tanvir put self.loadRecords() in viewWillAppear and one more thing is in `func parseJSON(jsonData:AnyObject)` add one line `storeList.removeAll()`

Comment: Thanks it worked. You can answer here and I will will mark accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is basically 2 things ....

1st is just put your `self.loadRecords()` in `viewWillAppear` method

and 2nd one remove all objects from array before parse it once again like

```
  func parseJSON(jsonData:AnyObject)
  { 
       storeList.removeAll()
       //....
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

After deleting data from mysql,

1) you will have to delete cell from tableview as follow.

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

in first argument you will have to pass array of indexpaths which cells you want to delete.

2) Or else you can again fetch data from Database & reload table..

```
//code for fetching data from database
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I have a method viewWillAppear where I have tableView.reloadData(). But still it does not work.

Comment: not on ViewWillAppear only, you ll also have to put when you delete row from table

Comment: After deleting , you have to reload data

Comment: The method for deleting json is called deleteData. But how can I call self.tableView.reloadData(). It will not work there.